# How to get peer address in event handler on error during bufferevent_socket_connect?

Tags: libevent

I didn't find a way to print peer's address in event handler on error during bufferevent_socket_connect. Can anybody help?

What I tried:

1. Using getpeername() on bufferevent_getfd() fails becouse connection is not established
2. Transmitting peer's address in the last parameter of event handler fails too, because of this pointer changes on next connection attempt to another peer.

code example:

```
void eventcb(struct bufferevent *bev, short events, void *ptr)
{
    if (events & BEV_EVENT_ERROR)
    {
        // I whant to print peer's address on error in bufferevent_socket_connect
        bufferevent_free(bev);
    }
}

int main()
{
    ...
    struct sockaddr_storage obj;
    ...
    while(get_next_obj(obj))
    {
        evutil_socket_t sock = socket(obj.ss_family, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        evutil_make_socket_nonblocking(sock);
        evutil_make_listen_socket_reuseable(sock);
        evutil_make_socket_closeonexec(sock);
        struct bufferevent *evbev = 
            bufferevent_socket_new(evbase, sock, 0);
        bufferevent_set_timeouts(evbev, &sec5, &sec5);
        bufferevent_setcb(evbev, readcb, NULL, eventcb, evbase);
        bufferevent_enable(evbev, EV_READ|EV_WRITE);
        bufferevent_write(evbev, some_data.data(), some_data_sz);
        if(bufferevent_socket_connect(evbev, (struct sockaddr *)&obj, sizeof(sockaddr_storage)) < 0) {
            continue;
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```